# How do you import a list from another .py or .ipynb into a program in jupyter notebook. i am attempting to import a list of words for my hangman game

Tags: python, list, import, jupyter

```
import random
import nbimporter
from words2 import wordlist
import string

def get_valid_word(wordlist):
    word= random.choice(wordlist) #randomly chooses something from list
    while '-' in word or ' ' in word:
        word= random.choice(wordlist)

    return word.upper()
```

Comment: All I see is code.  Where are the results and/or problem?  Without `words2` we can't test your code.  Also your code has a function def, but does not attempt to run it.

Comment: I attempted to copy and paste the entirety of my code into the text box but I am getting a formatting error. even though my code is formatted properly by python standards anyway. I am at a lost

Comment: I am fairly new to stackoverflow if you could not tell. but after spending hours trying to figure out how to upload some more of my code and failing I think I might just have to go without knowing how to import things. lets see how that goes

Comment: i will say that words2 is just code that contains 1 variable called wordlist. this variable contains a list of bout 1500 words. so if you could make a simple list with a few words to import and call this function. that should replicate my problem pretty accurately. considering the code above retrieves a word from the list wordlist and returns the word in capital letters without any '-' or ' ' in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Notebook_1

name_list = ['ab', 'cd']
%store name_list

Notebook_2

%store -r name_list
print(name_list)
```

Try this, it will work